# Как осуществить DISTINCT или группировку по двум полям-ключам?

Tags: sql, laravel

Скажу сразу, что задача решается в ларавел 8-10. У меня есть две таблицы users и messages.

Таблица "users" имеет ключевое уникальное поле "id" и "name".
Таблица "messages" имеет поля "id" (инкремент), "user_id"(кто написал сообщение), "to_user_id" (получатель-юзер), "text" (текст), "created_at" (дата создания).

В SQL это выглядело бы так:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id int,
  name varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Mary'),
(3, 'Jeff'),
(4, 'Bill'),
...
(25, 'Bob');

CREATE TABLE messages(
  id int,
  user_id int,
  to_user_id int,
  text varchar(255),
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO messages VALUES
(1, 1, 23, 'message-text1', '2023-05-10'),
(2, 25, 5, 'Сообщение 2', '2023-05-11'),
(3, 12, 3, 'text 3', '2023-05-12'),
(4, 5, 25, 'message 4', '2023-05-12'),
(5, 5 , 12, 'message 5', '2023-05-15'),
(5, 23 , 1, 'message 6', '2023-05-16'),
(5, 1 , 5, 'message 7', '2023-05-17'),
(5, 5 , 1, 'message 8', '2023-05-17'),
(5, 2 , 10, 'message 5', '2023-05-17');
```

В полях user_id и to_user_id коды пользователей, которые общаются между собой. Нужно составить список всех уникальных сообщений между пользователями, только последнее сообщение по дате в каждой паре id (user_id и to_user_id), например юзеры с номерами 5 и 25. 5-й может написать сообщение 25-ому, либо наоборот 25-й может написать сообщение 5-ому. И таких пар сообщений в таблице может быть много (1 и 23, 25 и 5, 12 и 3, 5 и 25, 5 и 12, 23 и 1, 1 и 5, 5 и 1, 2 и 10). Из этой двух пар возможных комбинаций диалога между двумя пользователями в выборке нужно только последнее сообщение их. И так для каждой уникальной пары пользователей общающихся между собой.

Пишу что-то вроде такого, но это не то:

```
$messages = DB::table('messages')
             ->join('users as users1', 'messages.user_id', '=', 'users1.id')
             ->join('users as users2', 'messages.to_user_id', '=', 'users2.id')
             ->select('user_id, to_user_id, users1.name, users2.name, text, created_at')
             ->groupBy('1, 2')
             ->latest()
             ->get();
```

Данные таблицы messages допустим такие:

user_id  |  to_user_id | created_at

1        |      23     | 10.05.2023
25       |      5      | 11.05.2023
12       |      3      | 12.05.2023
5        |      25     | 12.05.2023
5        |      12     | 15.05.2023
23       |      1      | 16.05.2023
1        |      5      | 17.05.2023
5        |      1      | 17.05.2023
2        |      10     | 17.05.2023
___________________________________

Соответственно в выборку результата должны попасть следующие строки:

user_id  |  to_user_id | created_at

12       |      3      |12.05.2023 
5        |      25     |12.05.2023 
5        |      12     |15.05.2023 
23       |      1      |16.05.2023 
5        |      1      |17.05.2023 
2        |      10     | 17.05.2023
___________________________________

Есть еще объекты модели messages и users. Можно в ларавел через них сформировать теоретически запрос. Но пока все это связывает две таблицы и выводит, скорее всего (если я не ошибся в запросе), сгруппированные значения по user_id и to_user_id. Судя по всему тут будут выведены все сообщения от пользователей, а не только последние из сообщений пользователями друг другу. Как сделать правильный запрос? Подскажет кто-нибудь?

Comment: ```GROUP BY LEAST(user_id, to_user_id), GREATEST(user_id, to_user_id)```

Comment: @Akina, напомню, что у меня mysql. Нету функции LEAST, только MIN можно использовать. И зачем GREATEST? Чтобы найти максимальный код юзера?

Comment: *напомню, что у меня mysql. Нету функции LEAST* Ну ерунды-то не говори... [LEAST() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least).

Comment: @Akina, да точно такая функция есть в mysql. Но приведет ли такой запрос к тому виду выборки данных, который я представил в таблицах кодов? Только сгруппирует, а не удалит лишние записи. Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @Akina, дополнил вопрос sql данными. Можно просто показать на sql, ну либо конкретно для ларавел - это для знатоков ларавел.

Comment: Хреново добавил. В messages есть user_id int и to_user_id, отсутствующие в users. И имя поля text - недопустимо, ибо keyword.

Comment: *"created_at" (дата создания)* Тип данных TIMESTAMP - это как бы не только дата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id int,
  name varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Mary'),
(3, 'Jeff'),
(4, 'Bill'),
(5, 'Jim'),
(12, 'Kate'),
(23, 'Jane'),
(25, 'Bob');

CREATE TABLE messages(
  id int,
  user_id int,
  to_user_id int,
  text varchar(255),
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO messages VALUES
(1, 1, 23, 'message-text1', '2023-05-10'),
(2, 25, 5, 'Сообщение 2', '2023-05-11'),
(3, 12, 3, 'text 3', '2023-05-12'),
(4, 5, 25, 'message 4', '2023-05-12'),
(5, 5 , 12, 'message 5', '2023-05-15'),
(6, 23 , 1, 'message 6', '2023-05-16'),
(7, 1 , 5, 'message 7', '2023-05-17'),
(8, 5 , 1, 'message 8', '2023-05-17'),
(9, 2 , 10, 'message 5', '2023-05-17');
```

Поскольку `created_at` неуникально, за признак "раньше - позже" взято значение `messages.id`.

```
-- решение для версии 5.x
SELECT u1.name, u2.name, m1.`text`, m1.created_at
FROM messages m1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) id
       FROM messages
       GROUP BY LEAST(user_id, to_user_id),
                GREATEST(user_id, to_user_id)               
      ) m2 USING (id)
JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = m1.user_id
JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = m1.to_user_id
```

| name | name | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | John | message 8 | 2023-05-17 00:00:00 |
| Jane | John | message 6 | 2023-05-16 00:00:00 |
| Kate | Jeff | text 3 | 2023-05-12 00:00:00 |
| Jim | Kate | message 5 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 |
| Jim | Bob | message 4 | 2023-05-12 00:00:00 |

```
-- решение для версии 8+
WITH 
cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(user_id, to_user_id), 
                                         GREATEST(user_id, to_user_id)
                            ORDER BY id DESC) rn
  FROM messages
)
SELECT u1.name, u2.name, cte.`text`, cte.created_at
FROM cte
JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = cte.user_id
JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = cte.to_user_id
WHERE cte.rn = 1
```

| name | name | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | John | message 6 | 2023-05-16 00:00:00 |
| Jim | John | message 8 | 2023-05-17 00:00:00 |
| Kate | Jeff | text 3 | 2023-05-12 00:00:00 |
| Jim | Kate | message 5 | 2023-05-15 00:00:00 |
| Jim | Bob | message 4 | 2023-05-12 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kkeYPFtG)

На Laravel переведёте самостоятельно...